# Create UITabBar programmatically in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm attempting to programmatically add unique viewControllers to TabBarItems and create a UITabBar controller using an IBOutlet.

Here is my code for creating UITabBar

```
public class TabBarViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var tabBarCnt: UITabBar!

   override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     self.tabBarCnt.delegate = self
     createTabBarController()
   }

   func createTabBarController() {

        let firstVC = FirstViewController()
        firstVC.name = nameVal
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 0)
        firstVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);

        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        firstVC.name = nameVal
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 0)
        firstVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);

        let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
        thirdVC.name = nameVal
        thirdVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 0)
        thirdVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);


        tabBarCnt.items = [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC]
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tabBarCnt)
    }

}
```

It does not display any viewControllers.

How to create a UITabBar based on my code?

Answer (score 2):

A `UITabBar` does not display any view controllers. It only displays tabs.

Most likely you should be using a `UITabBarController`, not a standalone `UITabBar`. Change your `TabBarViewController` class to extend `UITabBarController` instead of `UIViewController` and eliminate the `UITabBar` outlet.

```
public class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViewControllers()
    }

    func setupViewControllers() {
        let firstVC = FirstViewController()
        firstVC.name = nameVal
        firstVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil)
        firstVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);

        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        firstVC.name = nameVal
        firstVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil)
        firstVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);

        let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
        thirdVC.name = nameVal
        thirdVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "ico_active", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil)
        thirdVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);

        viewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC]
    }
}
```

Note that you do not need to create new instances of `UITabBarItem` for each view controller.

You can also add an extension to your view controller to handle the tab bar controller delegate methods. Something like the following:

```
extension TabBarViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Handle the user selecting a different tab
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Right now implemented using UITabBarController. Thanks for answering